# Help Refactoring Entity Framework 4 Query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, eager-loading

I have two entities:

- **Location**
- **Post**

It's a *1..** between **Location** and **Post**.

**Location** is abstract, i have many derived entities such as **City**. I use Table-Per-Type inheritance for my model.

I'm trying to write the following query: (simplified)

- Get Top 20 Cities, and include the "Top Rated Post" (highest rating).

So, **Location** has a navigational property called **Posts**.

A thing to keep in mind - **i disable lazy loading, hence i must eager load, or perform two queries**.

So, here is the query i currently have. Keep in mind, i need to return an `ICollection<Location>` from this method:

```
public ICollection<Location> FindTopTwentyLocations()
{
    var results = new List<Location>();

    var cities = locationRepository
                   .Find()
                   .OfType<City>()
                   .Select(x => new
                    {
                       Location = x,
                       TopPost = x.Posts.OrderByDescending(r => x.Rating).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).Take(20).ToList();

    foreach (var city in cities)
    {
       var aggregatedCity = city.Location;
       aggregatedCity.Posts = new List<Post> { aggregatedCity.TopPost };
       results.Add(city);
    }

    return results;
}
```

So essentially, im grabbing the first 20 cities, projecting into an anonymous type so i can grab the top post, then looping through that collection of anonymous types to shove the post back into the "**City**" object, in order to be added to the return type of `List<Location>`.

- I can't use `.Include` as that will return **all posts**
- I don't want to execute 2 queries
- I must use anonymous type projection otherwise it will throw an EF error (cannot translate query)

With those points in mind, is there a better way we can do this? I'm reasonably happy with the `var cities` query, but i don't really like the looping/copying over of the anonymous type properties to my model entity.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've also been noticing the projection to the anonymous type is losing the eager loaded **Location** associations i am retrieving.

E.g

```
var query = locationRepository.Find().OfType<City>().Include("State").ToList();
```

works - all "State" associations returned.

but:

```
var query = locationRepository.Find().OfType<City>().Include("State").Select(x => new {
   Location = x,
   TopPost = x.Posts.OrderByDescending(r => x.Rating).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

Results in all the "State" associations being null.

Bizarre!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to keep this open for a while and see other answers, but i'm sticking with what i have for now.

One point i'd like to mention regarding my EDIT above.

Projecting a eager-loaded query to an anonymous type appears to lose the included association. I have no idea why.

A workaround i used was to include the eager-loaded association in the anonymous type:

```
var cities = locationRepository
                   .Find()
                   .OfType<City>()
                   .Select(x => new
                    {
                       Location = x,
                       State = x.State, // include association in anon type
                       TopPost = x.Posts.OrderByDescending(r => x.Rating).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).Take(20).ToList();

    foreach (var city in cities)
    {
       var aggregatedCity = city.Location;
       aggregatedCity.State = city.State; // copy anon type association over
       aggregatedCity.Posts = new List<Post> { aggregatedCity.TopPost };
       results.Add(city);
    }
```

And that seems to work.

In terms of refactoring the code, i don't think the `var cities` query can be optimized. I tried to move the `foreach` left-to-right copying into another `.Select` projection (e.g after the query has been materialized - after the `.ToList()`), but in order to do that i would have to left-to-right copy ALL of the properties, e.g:

```
var cities = locationRepository
                   .Find()
                   .OfType<City>()
                   .Select(x => new
                    {
                       Location = x,
                       State = x.State, // include association in anon type
                       TopPost = x.Posts.OrderByDescending(r => x.Rating).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).Take(20).ToList().Select(x => new City
                    {
                       CityName = Location.Name,
                       State = State,
                       // etc etc
                    });
```

Considering i have 20+ properties on my entities, i do not want to do this. Brings me back to the painful world of Linq-To-Sql and POCO's.

As i said - open to other suggestions.

**EDIT**

I ended up using a stored procedure here. My code works, but it's 100+ lines. I'd rather have those 100+ lines abstracted away into a stored procedure.

Also, this result is basically read-only (i don't need the entities in the graph - i just get the results, display them and be done with it).

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but can you not do something like this?

```
var cities = locationRepository 
                   .Find() 
                   .OfType<City>() 
                   .Select(x => 
                    { 
                       x.Posts = x.Posts.OrderByDescending(r => x.Rating).Take(1);
                       return x;
                    }).Take(20).ToList();
```

or if EF complains about altering the `Posts` property then create a new Location object & add the Post in the select operation.

Comment: Interesting, i'll give that a go - not sure if it will work but i'll try. Oh and i can't create a new Location as it's abstract - i use generics so my code is actually `.OfType<T>` (`where T : Location`). I can't "new up" a city (for example), because i'd have to left-to-right copy all the properties over. I'll try your example though and let you know.

Comment: Nope, couldn't get it to work. Says "Cannot convert IEnumerable<Post> to ICollection<Post>". And if i try and do `.ToList()` it says "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree". No matter, i've got it working better/faster with a SPROC. Appreciate your help though. :)

Comment: Fair enough, I know sometimes it can be difficult to set those ORM collection properties.  Using a stored proc is always good idea when the query gets complex.